# Failure while attempt to find specific cell in table view swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to find specific cell class in my table view. I use following code:

```
func setConfirmEnabledIfNeed(){
        let ip = IndexPath(row: 8, section: 0)
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: ip) as? ConfirmBtnCell {
            print("find confirm cell")
        }
        let c = tableView.cellForRow(at: ip) as? ConfirmBtnCell
        print("type of cell \(type(of: c))")
    }
```

print("find confirm cell") is never called, however, second print output: `type of cell Optional<ConfirmBtnCell>`, what is obviously what i need. But why first print not called?

My cell for row look like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let item = viewModel.items[indexPath.row]
    switch item {
    case .selectable(let value, let placeholder, let type):
        let selectionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SelectionCell") as! SelectionCell
        if let placeholder = placeholder { selectionCell.setPlaceholder(placeholder) }
        if let text = value as? String, !text.isEmpty { selectionCell.hidePlaceholder();
            selectionCell.textLbl.text = text }
        if let date = value as? Date { selectionCell.hidePlaceholder();
            selectionCell.textLbl.text = DateFormatterUtil.getReadableStringFromDate(date) }
        return selectionCell
    case .back:
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BackBtnCell") as! BackBtnCell
    case .confirm:
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ConfirmBtnCell") as! ConfirmBtnCell
    case .editableNumbers(let text, let placeholder, let type):
        let editableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextEditCell") as! TextEditCell
        editableCell.setup(isNumerical: true)
        if let placeholder = placeholder { editableCell.setPlaceholder(placeholder) }
        if let text = text {editableCell.hidePlaceholder(); editableCell.txtf.text = text }
        editableCell.textChanged = {[weak self] text in
            guard let text = text else { return }
            if type == .sumCash {
                self?.viewModel.collectedInfo[CorrectionChequeViewModel.infoKeys.sumCash.rawValue] = text
                self?.setConfirmEnabledIfNeed()
            }

            if type == .sumElectronic {
                self?.viewModel.collectedInfo[CorrectionChequeViewModel.infoKeys.sumElectronic.rawValue] = text
            }
        }
        return editableCell
    case .editableText(let text, let placeholder, let type):
        let editableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextEditCell") as! TextEditCell
        editableCell.setup(isNumerical: false)
        if let placeholder = placeholder { editableCell.setPlaceholder(placeholder) }
        if let text = text {editableCell.hidePlaceholder(); editableCell.txtf.text = text }
        editableCell.textChanged = {[weak self] text in
            guard let text = text else { return }
            if type == .sumCash {
                self?.viewModel.collectedInfo[CorrectionChequeViewModel.infoKeys.description.rawValue] = text
            }

            if type == .sumElectronic {
                self?.viewModel.collectedInfo[CorrectionChequeViewModel.infoKeys.number.rawValue] = text
            }
        }
        return editableCell
     default:
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

UPDATE: 
I find that code work if it's not called from table view cellForRow method. I tried to launch that block of code with dispatch_after, and it works.

Comment: The second print statement is not in an `if let` block so it will always be called. Your `cellForRow` must be returning nil both times.

Comment: @Chris how to get my cell as specific class?

Comment: Have you declared `ConfirmBtnCell` as a subclass of `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: If the tableview cell at that index was a different class, it cannot be cast to `CustomBtnCell`

Comment: @Chris it subclasss of BaseCell that inherit from UITableViewCell

Comment: Try casting it like this: `as? UITableViewCell` to see if that works. If so, it’s a problem with the subclassing presumably.

Comment: The problem must be the tableview not finding a `ConfirmBtnCell` at that index path.

Comment: Could you share your delegate’s `tableview.cellForRowAt` method?

Comment: @Chris ok, please take a look.

Comment: Did you get it working ok? I can’t find a problem with your code.

Comment: @Chris my code snippet work if only i did not call it from cellForRow method, thats odd.

Answer (score 3):

In your `if` statement, the value for `tableView.cellForRow(at: ip) as? ConfirmBtnCell` is nil, so you never enter the block.

In the second statement (`let c = tableView.cellForRow(at: ip) as? ConfirmBtnCell`), the value of `c` is an `Optional<ConfirmBtnCell>`. If you unwrap the optional, you will see that its unwrapped value is also a nil.

If your row is not visible, `tableView.cellForRow` will return a nil even when the cell is set. See the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow).

Comment: i want to get my ConfirmBtnCell, how to do that? And why it's nil?

Comment: Does the index path definitely exist in the tableview?

Comment: @Chris yes, it exist.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban we'd need to see your code for `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Comment: @Dimitry i updated answer. my code snippet not work when i call it from cellForRow method.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Check the documentation for `cellForRow`: `An object representing a cell of the table, or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.` If the cell is *not visible*, it will return a nil.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Can you please vote the answer as the correct answer if it solved your problem?